# Can I extend a type with another type?

Tags: typescript, types, extends

Consider the following type:

```
export type Collections = {
  users: User
  business: Business
  permissions: Permissions
  cards: Card
}

// note the Collections[keyof Collections] are just some custom types
// that are objects, but are irrelevant for the question
```

and let's say I want to create a type that extends the aforementioned type in `Record<keyof Collections, unknown>`

I know [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) recently introduced the [`statisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator, but that is only useful for `const` not extending the types themelves.

I know the shape of my desired type, i.e.

```
export type SubCollections = {
  cards: [CardLog, CardActions]
  users: [UserLog]
}
```

this works, however it's not very practical, because when I want to use a function

```
const subcollection = <K extends keyof Collections, S extends SubCollections[K]>(
  collection: K,
  sub: S
) => // ...
```

This throws a TypeError:

> Type `K` cannot be used index type `SubCollections`

Which obviously I understand why it happens. I know I could create an artificial type-narrower i.e.

```
type SharedKey<K extends keyof Collection> = K extends keyof SubCollections
 ? K
 : never

export const subcollection = <
  K extends keyof Collections,
  S extends SharedKey<K>
>(collection: K, subcol: S) => // ...
// ^ this works!
```

But this still feels rather clumsy if I had to individually narrow the argument in every single use-case.

Is there perhaps a way I could tell typescript, that the two types share the same keys?

```
// something akin to (obviously this is invalid syntax)
export type SubCollections extends Record<keyof Collections, unknown[]> = {
  cards: [CardLog, CardActions]
  users: [UserLog]
}
```

Comment: What is the relantionship between Card, CardActions and CardLog and User with UserLog?

Comment: No direct relation. Can be any object for all intents and purposes. The only direct relation is that the Collections and Subcollections share the same keys (to be precise, keyof Subcollection must be of keyof Collections, but it is not an exact map (i.e. some keys can be omitted)

Comment: But... the two types *don't* share the same keys and that's why you get an error... What if `K` is "business" in your example? Then it is unsound to use it as a key to `SubCollections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this might helps ?

```
type Commonkeys<A, B> = keyof A extends infer keyofA ? (keyofA extends keyof B ? keyofA : never) : never;

type AAA = Commonkeys<Collections, SubCollections>;
//  type AAA = "cards" | "users"

const subcollection = <K extends Commonkeys<Collections, SubCollections>, S extends SubCollections[K]>(collection: K, sub: S) => {};
```

---

**Update thanks to vera :**

```
    const subcollection = <K extends keyof Collections & keyof SubCollections, S extends SubCollections[K]>(
  collection: K,
  sub: S
) => {};
```

Seems so simple now ...

Comment: `Commonkeys` could be written as `keyof A & keyof B`.

Comment: Waoow. I didn't know this one